# VBA Breakpoint Introducing Errors?

Tags: vba, debugging, dictionary, vbscript, breakpoints

Has anyone ever run into breakpoints in the VBA console actually introducing errors? How could this possibly happen?

The short version of the story is that I have some code that works as expected when executed with no breakpoints toggled on. However, when breakpoints were toggled on in a few locations (in a subroutine and in a class method), the code would throw inexplicable errors when stepping through the code. I would ordinarily find this an extremely unlikely explanation, but after spending 2.5 days trying to debug the code only to discover that it executes properly with breakpoints turned off, I'm having trouble understanding what could have been the problem.

**Details:**

Two different errors occur when breakpoints are on.

```
Run-time error '457': This key is already associated with an element of this collection
```

and

```
Run-time error '424': Object required
```

The 457 error would occur after stepping through the code from the breakpoint to the line

```
 dictE.Add M.SubMatches.Item(0), tmpQ
```

where one of the conditions for reaching this line of code was that `dictE.Exists(M.SubMatches.Item(0))` was False.

The 424 error would occur after choosing `Debug` when the 457 error occurred. In a similarly zany manner, the error would be thrown by the (different) line

```
 pathE = dictE.Item(Matches.Item(i).SubMatches.Item(0)).InFile
```

where one of the conditions for reaching this line of code was that `dictE.Exists(Matches.Item(i).SubMatches.Item(0))` was True (and the `.InFile` property of the object is always defined).

Both of these errors occur in the same method of a custom class. I'd like to post all of the relevant code, but it's work-related and proprietary. Any ideas why this would happen? Is this a known issue? I tried googling for reports of similar problems, but I found nothing.

Comment: Are you using the Watch window while on a breakpoint? See @assylias's comment under the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803708/how-to-monitor-the-values-in-a-dictionary-in-the-excel-vba-watch-window  Basically there seems to be someproblem with checking key values for a dictionary object while in break mode - checking a non-existent key value can actually add that key.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, I had a watch on one of the problem values in the Watch window, but I am unsure if I had it there the whole time. I can try to reproduce the problem on a fresh copy of input files tomorrow with no watches defined.

Comment: +1 @TimWilliams checking a non-existing key value **will** add that key to the dictionary :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it relates to your issue, but here's an illustration of how unexpected things can happen while using a dictionary and halted on a breakpoint...

Place a breakpoint on `Debug.Print "Break"` and then run this code:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim d As Object

    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    d.Add "K1", "first"
    d.Add "K2", "second"
    d.Add "K3", "third"

    Debug.Print d.Count '>>3 - as expected
    Debug.Print "Break" ' Enter '? d("blah")' in Immediate pane
                        '                      while halted here...
    Debug.Print d.Count '>> 4 ! key "blah" was added...

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This was it. I tested my code with breakpoints on but no expressions in the watch window, and it worked as expected. What a horrendous bug! I spent two days pulling my hair out trying to fix something that wasn't broken because of this.