# Insert multiple dictionaries in an array by using a loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary, for-loop

I have a problem by filling an array in excel vba by using a loop.
Actually I would like to fill the dictionary `myitem` the following way:
`produkt1` and `produkt2` may be both dictionaries.

```
myitem("productionOrderItems")=Array(produkt1, produkt2).
```

Since I don't now how many times I have a `produkt` I am using a loop to create the dictionary `produkt`. 
Everytime the dictionary `produkt` is created and filled I would like to assign it to an `Array` just like I described above.
The following code shows the loop to create the dictionary. But in that case obviously only the last dictionary (`i=counter`) is created.
`counter` is the amount of products I would like to assign to the `Array`.

```
myitem As New Dictionary

For i = 1 To counter
    Dim produkt As New Dictionary
    zeile = 2 + i
    produkt("id") = Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 1).Value
    Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 1).Value = ""
    produkt("actualWithdrawalQuantity") = Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 2).Value
    Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 2).Value = ""
    produkt("articleId") = Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 3).Value
    Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 3).Value = ""
    produkt("articleNumber") = Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 4).Value
    Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 4).Value = ""
    produkt("createdDate") = Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 5).Value
    Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 5).Value = ""
    produkt("positionNumber") = Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 6).Value
    Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 6).Value = ""
    produkt("quantity") = Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 7).Value
    Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 7).Value = ""
    produkt("targetWithdrawalDate") = Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 8).Value
    Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 8).Value = ""
    produkt("targetWithdrawalQuantity") = Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 9).Value
    Tabelle6.Cells(zeile, 9).Value = ""
    myitem("productionOrderItems") = Array(produkt)
Next
```

Maybe someone has an idea how to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that

```
myitem("productionOrderItems") = Array(produkt)
```

always overwrites `myitem("productionOrderItems")` with a new array and doesn't preserve the old one. So in the end there is only the last "new" array in it.

What you need to do is to extend the existing array by one entry each time:

```
Dim tmpArr As Variant
tmpArr = myitem("productionOrderItems") 'read existing array into temp array
If IsEmpty(tmpArr) Then
    tmpArr = Array(produkt) 'first time we need to generate a array
Else 'for all other times we need to append to the existing array
    ReDim Preserve tmpArr(UBound(tmpArr) + 1) 'resize existing array by one
    Set tmpArr(UBound(tmpArr)) = produkt 'add the product to the newly added array entry
End If
myitem("productionOrderItems") = tmpArr 'write temp array back to dictionary
```

Comment: I am using the array to set up a PUT request. 
When finishing the request the error "productionorderItems: duplicate id" occurs. 
I am wondering if the Array does contain duplicated ids. But for that I have to show a MsgBox that shows the produkt array.

Can you tell me how?
Or do you have an idea why the error with the duplicated id occurs?

Comment: you need a loop to output all items of an array or dictionary: [How to monitor the values in a Dictionary in the Excel VBA watch window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803708/how-to-monitor-the-values-in-a-dictionary-in-the-excel-vba-watch-window). If my answer is the solution to your original question please consider marking it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was:
The loop worked but the "produkt" dictionary haven't been overwritten so that two time the same "produkt" have been inserted.
I circumvented that issue by setting produkt to nothing in the beginning of the loop.
Thanks for your help!