# Looping through members of a collection, how can I get the member's key?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have to move a bunch of spinner objects to be right next to a set of cells.

For each spinner I need to run these statements

```
Worksheets("Serial").spnAspect.Left = Worksheets("Serial").Range("I12").Left - Worksheets("Serial").spnAspect.Width
Worksheets("Serial").spnAspect.Top = Worksheets("Serial").Range("I12").Top + Worksheets("Serial").Range("I12").Height / 2 _
                                        - Worksheets("Serial").spnAspect.Height / 2
```

So I wanted to make this a bit more tidy so I made the following sub.
The only issue I'm having here is how to tell it which cell to line up each spinner with.  This is the "I12"  which in each iteration should be thisControl 's key in the collection.

```
Sub MoveSpinners()

    Dim myControls As New Collection
    Dim thisControl As Object
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet

    myControls.Add Worksheets("Serial").spnHeight, "I11"
    myControls.Add Worksheets("Serial").spnAspect, "I12"
    myControls.Add Worksheets("Serial").spnCropleft, "I13"
    myControls.Add Worksheets("Serial").spnCropRight, "I14"
    myControls.Add Worksheets("Serial").spnCropTop, "I15"
    myControls.Add Worksheets("Serial").spnCropBottom, "I16"

    Set mySheet = Worksheets("Serial")

    For Each thisControl In myControls

        thisControl.Left = mySheet.Range("I12").Left - thisControl.Width
        thisControl.Top = mySheet.Range("I12").Top + thisControl.Height / 2 _
                                        - thisControl.Height / 2
    Next

End Sub
```

This is the same question as [Get the key of an item on a Collection object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738412/get-the-key-of-an-item-on-a-collection-object) , which in that case was answered by "use a dictionary object instead" but in my case it doesn't work as it is less tidy than just copy-pasting the same lines a whole bunch of times

Other alternative I am considering is a 
fMoveSpinner (thisSpinner as object, myDestination as range) but I was hoping to keep this small MoveSpinner subroutine self-contained.

If you have a better idea I would be glad to hear it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I refactored your code to use a Scripting Dictionary. It looks pretty tidy to me!

The keys and items of a Scripting Dictionary can both be objects.  Here I stored the control as a key and the range as the item.  In this way, when you access a key control you easily get the item range as a reference.

### Before and After

[image]

### Code

```
Sub MoveSpinners2()

    Dim myControls As Object
    Dim thisControl As Object
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long

    Set myControls = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Worksheets("Serial")

        myControls.Add .spnHeight, .Range("I11")
        myControls.Add .spnAspect, .Range("I12")
        myControls.Add .spnCropleft, .Range("I13")
        myControls.Add .spnCropRight, .Range("I14")
        myControls.Add .spnCropTop, .Range("I15")
        myControls.Add .spnCropBottom, .Range("I16")

    End With

    For Each thisControl In myControls

        thisControl.Left = myControls(thisControl).Left - thisControl.Width
        thisControl.Top = myControls(thisControl).Top + thisControl.Height / 2 _
                          - thisControl.Height / 2
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I really like this, I had no idea the key could be something other than a string or number. Thanks ! Very elegant !

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example on how to iterate the keys of a collection, however, I think using a dictionary would actually be cleaner given what you are trying to do.

Anyway, here is an example:

```
Sub Iterate_Keys_Collection()
    Dim myControls As New Collection
    Dim thisControl As Variant

    myControls.Add Array("first key", "I11"), "I11"
    myControls.Add Array("second key", "I12"), "I12"
    myControls.Add Array("third key", "I13"), "I13"

    For Each thisControl In myControls
        If thisControl(0) = "first key" Then
            MsgBox (thisControl(0)) ' Print the 'first key'
                                    ' The Value is in thisControl(1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: OK, you are storing string arrays in the collection. Would it be possible to store the spinner object in the array instead of the string "first key" ? I know variant arrays can store objects but that would require at least an extra line (I think).  Is there a way to store the spinner object and the key string (or the actual range object) in the array and do this with a single statement ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll add my 0.02 cents with an `Array` approach, thus not relying on neither `Dictionary` nor `Collection` objects:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveSpinners3()
    Dim iSpn As Long
    Dim spnArr As Variant
    Dim shp As Shape

    spnArr = Array("I11", "spnHeight", "I12", "spnAspect", "I13", "spnCropleft", "I14", "spnCropRight", "I15", "spnCropTop", "I16", "spnCropBottom")

    With Worksheets("Serial")
        For iSpn = LBound(spnArr) To UBound(spnArr) Step 2
            Set shp = .Shapes(spnArr(iSpn + 1))
            shp.Left = .Range(spnArr(iSpn)).Left - shp.Width
            shp.Top = .Range(spnArr(iSpn)).Top + shp.Height / 2 - shp.Height / 2
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

to maintain a (quite) possibly useful *visual* pairing between ranges and spinbuttons names the above code could be rewritten taking advantage of the `VBA` continuation character:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveSpinners3()
    Dim iSpn As Long
    Dim spnArr As Variant
    Dim shp As Shape

    spnArr = Array("I11", "spnHeight", _
                   "I12", "spnAspect", _
                   "I13", "spnCropleft", _
                   "I14", "spnCropRight", _
                   "I15", "spnCropTop", _
                   "I16", "spnCropBottom")

    With Worksheets("Serial")
        For iSpn = LBound(spnArr) To UBound(spnArr) Step 2
            Set shp = .Shapes(spnArr(iSpn + 1))
            shp.Left = .Range(spnArr(iSpn)).Left - shp.Width
            shp.Top = .Range(spnArr(iSpn)).Top + shp.Height / 2 - shp.Height / 2
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

while a (final?) refactoring to split pure *aligning* rules code from *selecting* one could be the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveSpinners3()
    Dim iSpn As Long
    Dim spnArr As Variant
    Dim shp As Shape

    spnArr = Array("I11", "spnHeight", _
                   "I12", "spnAspect", _
                   "I13", "spnCropleft", _
                   "I14", "spnCropRight", _
                   "I15", "spnCropTop", _
                   "I16", "spnCropBottom")

    With Worksheets("Serial")
        For iSpn = LBound(spnArr) To UBound(spnArr) Step 2
            MoveSpin .Shapes(spnArr(iSpn + 1)), .Range(spnArr(iSpn))
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Sub MoveSpin(shp As Shape, rng As Range)
        shp.Left = rng.Left - shp.Width
        shp.Top = rng.Top + shp.Height / 2 - shp.Height / 2
End Sub
```

of which could be taken immediate advantage to enhance OP's code aligning rule and avoid possible spinbuttons overlapping due to insufficient rows height as follows:

```
Sub MoveSpin(shp As Shape, rng As Range)
        rng.RowHeight = shp.Height '<--| make rows height match spinbutton one
        shp.Left = rng.Left - shp.Width
        shp.Top = rng.Top + shp.Height / 2 - shp.Height / 2
End Sub
```